# How to perform a faster query on MySQL from Zabbix?

Tags: php, mysql, zabbix

I am trying to build a monitoring dashboard for my custom Network, the one that has been implemented in Zabbix does not meet my requirements.

[image]

The query I perform to pull this information.

```
SELECT  ll.UF
       ,ll.unidade AS metric
       ,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 0 AND AVG(ll.degra) = 0,3,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 0 AND AVG(ll.degra) = 1,3,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 0 AND AVG(ll.degra) > 0 AND AVG(ll.degra) < 1,3,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 1 AND AVG(ll.degra) = 0,0,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 1 AND AVG(ll.degra) = 1,1,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 1 AND AVG(ll.degra) > 0 AND AVG(ll.degra) < 1,1,if(AVG(ll.degra) = 0 AND AVG(ll.ONLINE) > 0 AND AVG(ll.ONLINE) < 1,2,if(AVG(ll.degra) = 1 AND AVG(ll.ONLINE) > 0 AND AVG(ll.ONLINE) < 1,2,if(AVG(ll.degra) > 0 AND AVG(ll.degra) < 1 AND AVG(ll.ONLINE) > 0 AND AVG(ll.ONLINE) < 1,2,3))))))))) AS value
FROM 
(
    SELECT  hh.*
           ,if(hh.falha=1,0,1) AS ONLINE
           ,if(hh.falha=2,1,0) AS degra
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  dfd1.*
               ,SUM(if(dfd2.name = 'Perda de Pacote' OR dfd2.name = 'Tempo de resposta de ping ICMP alto',2,if(dfd2.name = 'ICMP Ping Indisponível',1,0))) AS falha
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT  AT1.*
                   ,AT2.itemid
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT  hb.*
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT  HOST
                           ,LEFT(HOST,2)                                        AS UF
                           ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',2),'_',-1) AS Operadora
                           ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1) AS unidade
                           ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-1)                        AS tipo
                           ,if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'HS.' ,
                       'hospital',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'VI.' ,
                       'vidaeimagem',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),7) = 'HAPCLI.' ,
                       'hapclinica',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'PA.' ,
                       'prontoatendimento',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'CD.' ,
                       'centrodedistribuicao',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),8) = 'MEDPREV.' ,
                       'medprev',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),4) = 'LAB.' ,
                       'laboratorio',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),4) = 'ADM.' ,
                       'administrativo',if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),4) = 'AMB.' ,
                       'ambulatorio','outros' ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) AS modalidade
                           ,hostid
                    FROM hosts
                    WHERE STATUS = 0  
                ) AS hb
                LEFT JOIN hosts_groups AS idgr
                ON hb.hostid = idgr.hostid
                WHERE idgr.groupid = 15 
            ) AS AT1
            LEFT JOIN items AS AT2
            ON AT1.hostid = AT2.hostid
        ) AS dfd1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  gn2.itemid
                   ,gn1.name
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT  a1.*
                FROM events AS a1
                LEFT JOIN event_recovery AS a2
                ON a1.eventid = a2.eventid
                WHERE a2.r_eventid IS NULL 
                AND a1.value = 1 
            ) AS gn1
            LEFT JOIN functions AS gn2
            ON gn1.objectid = gn2.triggerid
            WHERE gn2.itemid IS NOT NULL 
        ) AS dfd2
        ON dfd1.itemid = dfd2.itemid
        GROUP BY  dfd1.host
    ) AS hh
) AS ll
GROUP BY  ll.unidade
ORDER BY ll.UF ASC
         ,VALUE desc
```

I was able to open the Zabbix database and make the queries I need, but the query took about 15 seconds and consumed a lot of processing (I used a lot of INNER JOIN between the bank tables).

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `hosts` (
    `hostid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `proxy_hostid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `host` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `flags` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `templateid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `proxy_address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `auto_compress` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `discover` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`hostid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `hosts_1` (`host`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `hosts_2` (`status`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `hosts_3` (`proxy_hostid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `hosts_4` (`name`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `c_hosts_3` (`templateid`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_hosts_1` FOREIGN KEY (`proxy_hostid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`hosts` (`hostid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `c_hosts_3` FOREIGN KEY (`templateid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`hosts` (`hostid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Table linking groups with host name

```
CREATE TABLE `hosts_groups` (
    `hostgroupid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hostid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `groupid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`hostgroupid`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `hosts_groups_1` (`hostid`, `groupid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `hosts_groups_2` (`groupid`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_hosts_groups_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hostid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`hosts` (`hostid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_hosts_groups_2` FOREIGN KEY (`groupid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`hstgrp` (`groupid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

table that links the items to trigger

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `itemid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hostid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    PRIMARY KEY (`itemid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `items_1` (`hostid`, `key_`(255)) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `items_3` (`status`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_items_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hostid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`hosts` (`hostid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

table that links the event_recovery to event

```
CREATE TABLE `event_recovery` (
    `eventid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `r_eventid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `c_eventid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `correlationid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `userid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `event_recovery_1` (`r_eventid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `event_recovery_2` (`c_eventid`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_event_recovery_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`events` (`eventid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_event_recovery_2` FOREIGN KEY (`r_eventid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`events` (`eventid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_event_recovery_3` FOREIGN KEY (`c_eventid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`events` (`eventid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

events

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
    `eventid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `source` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `object` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `objectid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `clock` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `value` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `acknowledged` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ns` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `severity` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `events_1` (`source`, `object`, `objectid`, `clock`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `events_2` (`source`, `object`, `clock`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Table Functions

```
CREATE TABLE `functions` (
    `functionid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `itemid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `triggerid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `parameter` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    PRIMARY KEY (`functionid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `functions_1` (`triggerid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `functions_2` (`itemid`, `name`, `parameter`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_functions_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itemid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`items` (`itemid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `c_functions_2` FOREIGN KEY (`triggerid`) REFERENCES `zabbix`.`triggers` (`triggerid`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=I
```

So I found out that if I did the queries separately and put the tables together through PHP, which is the language I am using to build the dashboard, it is much more efficient. However I am having work on correlating two queries into one using PHP.

Using PHP I make the requirement below:

```
<?PHP
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);



$path2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path2 .= "/SCL/db/protect.php";
include($path2);
    
   //this code is better identified at the beginning of this StackOverflow forum

    $geral = "select ll.UF, ll.unidade as metric, 
if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 0 AND avg(ll.degra) = 0,3,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 0 AND avg(ll.degra) = 1,3,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 0 AND avg(ll.degra) > 0 AND avg(ll.degra) < 1,3,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 1 AND avg(ll.degra) = 0,0,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 1 AND avg(ll.degra) = 1,1,if(AVG(ll.ONLINE) = 1 AND avg(ll.degra) > 0 AND avg(ll.degra) < 1,1,if(AVG(ll.degra) = 0 AND avg(ll.ONLINE) > 0 AND avg(ll.ONLINE) < 1,2,if(AVG(ll.degra) = 1 AND avg(ll.ONLINE) > 0 AND avg(ll.ONLINE) < 1,2,if(avg(ll.degra) > 0 AND avg(ll.degra) < 1 AND avg(ll.ONLINE) > 0 AND avg(ll.ONLINE) < 1,2,3))))))))) AS value 
FROM (SELECT hh.*, if(hh.falha=1,0,1) AS ONLINE, 
if(hh.falha=2,1,0) AS degra 
FROM (SELECT dfd1.*, sum(if(dfd2.name = 'Perda de Pacote' OR dfd2.name = 'Tempo de resposta de ping ICMP alto',2,if(dfd2.name = 'ICMP Ping Indisponível',1,0))) AS falha 
FROM (SELECT AT1.*, AT2.itemid FROM (SELECT hb.*
FROM (
            SELECT HOST,
            LEFT(HOST,2) AS UF,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',2),'_',-1) AS Operadora, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1) AS unidade, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-1) as tipo, 
            if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'HS.' , 'hospital', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'VI.' , 'vidaeimagem', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),7) = 'HAPCLI.' , 'hapclinica', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'PA.' , 'prontoatendimento', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),3) = 'CD.' , 'centrodedistribuicao', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),8) = 'MEDPREV.' , 'medprev', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),4) = 'LAB.' , 'laboratorio', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),4) = 'ADM.' , 'administrativo', if( LEFT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(HOST,'_',-2),'_',1),4) = 'AMB.' , 'ambulatorio', 'outros' ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )   as modalidade, 
            hostid 
            FROM hosts WHERE STATUS = 0 ) AS hb 
LEFT JOIN hosts_groups AS idgr 
ON hb.hostid = idgr.hostid 
WHERE idgr.groupid = 15) AS AT1 
LEFT JOIN items AS AT2 ON AT1.hostid = AT2.hostid) AS dfd1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gn2.itemid, gn1.name from (SELECT a1.* FROM events AS a1 LEFT JOIN event_recovery AS a2 ON a1.eventid = a2.eventid WHERE a2.r_eventid IS NULL AND a1.value = 1) AS gn1 LEFT JOIN functions AS gn2 ON gn1.objectid = gn2.triggerid WHERE gn2.itemid IS NOT NULL) AS dfd2
ON dfd1.itemid = dfd2.itemid
GROUP BY dfd1.host) AS hh) AS ll";

if(!empty($_POST["UF"]) && empty($_POST["modalidade"])){
     
    $uf = " '" . str_replace(" ","','",$_POST["UF"]) . "' ";
    
    $sql2 = $geral . "
    where ll.uf in (" . $uf . ")
    GROUP BY ll.unidade";

}elseif (empty($_POST["UF"]) && !empty($_POST["modalidade"])){

    $modalidade = " '" . str_replace(" ","','",$_POST["modalidade"]) . "' ";
    
    $sql2 = $geral . "
    where ll.modalidade in (" . $modalidade . ")
    GROUP BY ll.unidade";

}elseif (!empty($_POST["UF"]) && !empty($_POST["modalidade"])){

    $uf = " '" . str_replace(" ","','",$_POST["UF"]) . "' ";
    $modalidade = " '" . str_replace(" ","','",$_POST["modalidade"]) . "' ";
    
    $sql2 = $geral . "
    where ll.uf in (" . $uf . ")
    and ll.modalidade in (" . $modalidade . ")
    GROUP BY ll.unidade";

}else{

    $sql2 = $geral . "
    GROUP BY ll.unidade";

}

if(!empty($_POST["separa"])){
    $sql2 = $sql2 . "
    ORDER BY ll.UF ASC, VALUE desc";
}else{
    $sql2 = $sql2 . "
    ORDER BY VALUE desc";
}

if(!empty($_POST["falha"])){
    $sql2 = 'SELECT i.* FROM (' . $sql2 . ') AS i WHERE i.VALUE != 0';
}

                $stmt2 = $connect2->prepare($sql2);
                $result2 = $stmt2->execute();
                $val = $stmt2->rowCount();
                $ds = "";
                echo '<div class="lista">';

                if($val > 0){
                    while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                        
                        if(!empty($_POST["separa"])){
                            if ($ds <> $row->UF) {
                                $ds = $row->UF;
                                echo '</div><h2><span  class="line-center">' . $row->UF . '</span></h2><div class="lista">';
                            }
                        }
                        

                        if($row->value == 0){
                            $cor = 'green';
                        }elseif($row->value == 1){
                            $cor = 'orange';
                        }elseif($row->value == 2){
                            $cor = 'yellow';
                        }else{
                            $cor = 'red';
                        }
                        echo '<div class="usu"><span class="textON">' . $row->UF . "-" . str_replace("MEDPREV.","FMED.",str_replace("HS.","HOSP.",str_replace("HAPCLI.","HAP.",$row->metric))) . '</span><div class="circulo ' . $cor . '"></div></div>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }else{
                    echo "Sem Falha";
                    echo '</div>';
                }

?>
```

Do I get here asking for help to find a solution to this dilemma of mine if someone knows any tools that can help me manipulate the results of queries after having pulled the information?

Comment: Show the SQL. Show the `show create table {tablename}` to the tables in the query. Show the `EXPLAIN {query}` for your SQL. The images of the table don't have sufficient information to assess. Assuming your dataset is limited, correct [indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing) should correct the performance problem.

Writing joining in PHP is trying to do the database's job. Index it correctly and you won't need to.

Comment: Why you do not use zabbix php api?

Answer (score 1):

These might help some:

```
functions:  INDEX(triggerid, itemid)  -- replacing INDEX(triggered)
hosts:  INDEX(status, hosted, host)   -- replacing INDEX(status)
hosts_groups:  INDEX(groupid, hosted) -- replacing INDEX(grouped)
```

(There are probably other composite indexes that I missed.)

Flatten the query.  For example:

```
                SELECT  hb.*
                    FROM ( SELECT  HOST, LEFT(HOST,2) AS UF, hostid
                            FROM  hosts
                            WHERE  STATUS = 0 
                         ) AS hb
                    LEFT JOIN  hosts_groups AS idgr  ON hb.hostid = idgr.hostid
                    WHERE  idgr.groupid = 15
```

-->

```
         SELECT hb.HOST, LEFT(hb.HOST,2) AS UF, hb.hostid
             FROM hosts AS hb
             JOIN hosts_groups AS idgr
                   ON hb.hostid = idgr.hostid
             WHERE  idgr.groupid = 15
               AND  hb.STATUS = 0
```

(I did not loop for other flattenings.)

For `hosts_groups`, you can completely get rid of `hostgroupid` and promote the `UNIQUE` key to be `PRIMARY KEY`.  See: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table  Do similarly for any other many-to-many mapping tables.

Comment: Your tips are very helpful, however, I still have a performance problem, the whole query performed by mysql lasts about 15 seconds and I need a maximum of 5. And I'm not sure to change the database because it doesn't it's my development.

Comment: @AlbertoVitoriano - Let's see how much it flattened down to.  (I gave only one example; it feels like several can be done.)